# Villagers don't go inside the house

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As I am playing on peaceful mode, I have made my own house as a village. villagers consider this as a house. They enter and exit the house frequently. However at night time they tend to go inside house, but not through door, they try to go through walls and just stay at edge of wall. I think the block they are standing is considered inside by them. What should I do so that they will actually go inside the house?

minecraft PC: 1.10.2(vanilla)
[image]

Comment: You could push him in.

Comment: Break the door and make it face the other way.  It's possible you placed it incorrectly and the Villager AI thought outside was the house.

Answer (score 3):

The issue here seems to be that the block directly above where the villager is blocking the sky. Therefore, the villager AI assumes it is inside, when it is not. Adjust the position of the blocks at the top so they don't cover the area where the villagers keep going.

Comment: I will do that. by the end of the week. I have tight schedule